# ExpressJS & Websocket & session sharing

Tags: node.js, session, websocket, express

I'm trying to make a chat application based on Node.js. I'd like to force websocket server (ws library) to using ExpressJS session system. Unfortunately, I've got stuck. MemoryStore hashes used to get sessions' data are different than session IDs in cookies. Could somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Websocket server code part:

```
module.exports = function(server, clients, express, store) {
  server.on('connection', function(websocket) {
    var username;

    function broadcast(msg, from) {...}

    function handleMessage(msg) {...}

    express.cookieParser()(websocket.upgradeReq, null, function(err) {
        var sessionID = websocket.upgradeReq.cookies['sid'];

            //I see same value in Firebug
        console.log(sessionID);

            //Shows all hashes in store
            //They're shorter than sessionID! Why?
        for(var i in store.sessions)
            console.log(i);

        store.get(sessionID, function(err, session) {
                websocket.on('message', handleMessage);

                //other code - won't be executed until sessionID in store

                websocket.on('close', function() {...});
        });
    });
});
}
```

store object definition:

```
var store = new express.session.MemoryStore({
    reapInterval: 60000 * 10
});
```

app configuration:

```
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(app.get("staticPath")));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());

    app.use(express.session({
        store: store,
        secret: "dO_ob",
        key: "sid"
    }));
});
```

Part of main code:

```
var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var websocketServer = new websocket.Server({server: httpServer});
httpServer.listen(80);
```

Sample debugging output:

```
- websocket.upgradeReq.headers.cookie "sid=s%3A64a%2F6DZ4Mab8H5Q9MTKujmcw.U8PJJIR%2BOgONY57mZ1KtSPx6XSfcn%2FQPZ%2FfkGwELkmM"
- websocket.upgradeReq.cookies["sid"] "s:64a/6DZ4Mab8H5Q9MTKujmcw.U8PJJIR+OgONY57mZ1KtSPx6XSfcn/QPZ/fkGwELkmM"
- i "64a/6DZ4Mab8H5Q9MTKujmcw"
```

Comment: Simple, ugly workaround helps: sessionID = sessionID.match(/:[a-zA-Z0-9/+]+\./)[0].slice(1, -1), but I'd like to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, helped me out :) Did you ever find a proper solution to this?

Answer (score 29):

I found this works for me. Not sure it's the best way to do this though. First, initialize your express application:

```
// whatever your express app is using here...
var session = require("express-session");
var sessionParser = session({
    store: session_store,
    cookie: {secure: true, maxAge: null, httpOnly: true}
});
app.use(sessionParser);
```

Now, explicitly call the session middleware from the WS connection. If you're using the `express-session` module, the middleware will parse the cookies by itself. Otherwise, you might need to send it through your cookie-parsing middleware first.

If you're using the `websocket` module:

```
ws.on("request", function(req){
    sessionParser(req.httpRequest, {}, function(){
        console.log(req.httpRequest.session);
        // do stuff with the session here
    });
});
```

If you're using the `ws` module:

```
ws.on("connection", function(req){
    sessionParser(req.upgradeReq, {}, function(){
        console.log(req.upgradeReq.session);
        // do stuff with the session here
    });
});
```

For your convenience, here is a fully working example, using `express`, `express-session`, and `ws`:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var sessionParser = require('express-session')({
    secret:"secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
app.use(sessionParser);

app.get("*", function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.working = "yes!";
    res.send("<script>var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');</script>");
});

var ws = new require("ws").Server({server: server});
ws.on("connection", function connection(req) {
    sessionParser(req.upgradeReq, {}, function(){
        console.log("New websocket connection:");
        var sess = req.upgradeReq.session;
        console.log("working = " + sess.working);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: A bit late to the party, but your code won't compile. The line before the last is missing a `)`

Comment: @matejkramny Thanks, fixed now

Comment: What is object `ws`?

Comment: @AikonMogwai It is your websocket server object. e.g. `var WSServer = require("websocket").server; var ws = new WSServer(options);`

Comment: http://sgeproject.narod.ru/node/app.js is my code sample (express + ws), but `on request` is never raise.

Comment: Thanks. P.S. On windows `req.upgradeReq.headers.cookie` was `undefined` and `sess` too. I change `ws://localhost:3000` to `ws://127.0.0.1:3000` and problem is gone.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to get this working.  I think you need to specify the secret on cookieParser instead of session store.

Example from my app:

```
var app = express();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
var sessionStore = new RedisStore();
var cookieParser = express.cookieParser('some secret');

app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(express.session({store: sessionStore}));


wss.on('connection', function(rawSocket) {

  cookieParser(rawSocket.upgradeReq, null, function(err) {
    var sessionID = rawSocket.upgradeReq.signedCookies['connect.sid'];
    sessionStore.get(sessionID, function(err, sess) {
      console.log(sess);
    });
  });

});
```

Answer (score 12):

**Feb 2022 update:**

`verifyClient` is [now discouraged](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/377). New methods of doing this is described in [an issue comment](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/377#issuecomment-462152231).

Consult the [example code for session parsing and verification](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/express-session-parse/index.js) for a full usage example. Sample of the verification function:

```js
server.on('upgrade', function (request, socket, head) {
  console.log('Parsing session from request...');

  sessionParser(request, {}, () => {
    if (!request.session.userId) {
      socket.write('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n');
      socket.destroy();
      return;
    }

    console.log('Session is parsed!');

    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function (ws) {
      wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
    });
  });
});
```

**Original answer:**

In version 3.2.0 of `ws` you have to do it a bit differently.

There is a [full working example](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/express-session-parse/index.js) of express session parsing in the `ws` repo, specifically using a new feature `verifyClient`.

A very brief usage summary:

```
const sessionParser = session({
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: '$eCuRiTy',
  resave: false
})

const server = http.createServer(app)
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  verifyClient: (info, done) => {
    console.log('Parsing session from request...')
    sessionParser(info.req, {}, () => {
      console.log('Session is parsed!')
      done(info.req.session.userId)
    })
  },
  server
})

wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(`WS message ${message} from user ${req.session.userId}`)
  })
})
```

Comment: i dont see a verifyClient anywhere in the example linked above

Comment: @PirateApp it's defined on line 9.

Comment: no verifyClient anywhere here https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/express-session-parse/index.js

Comment: @PirateApp looks like a lot has happened since this answer was written, but the [`verifyClient`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/8a7016dc2fe4d9d63c428c67588d7c1f33a72e5c/lib/websocket-server.js#L286-L314) function is still valid. However, it seems like there are new ways of handling this now. I'll update the post with some clarification.

Answer (score 3):

WS v3.0.0 and above, has changed the behaviour so the given answers won't work out of the box for those versions. For current versions, the signature of the connection method is [function(socket, request)] and the socket no longer contains a reference to the request.

```
ws.on(
    'connection',
    function (socket, req)
    {
        sessionParser(
            req,
            {},
            function()
            {
                console.log(req.session);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Currently, below is my workaround which is working fine. I just don't know it's disadvantages and security. I just prevent the server from listening if it doesn't have a session. ([Share session from express-session to ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927250/share-session-from-express-session-to-ws))

I haven't fully tested this though.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.user_id) {
        // Socket authenticated
        server.listen(8080, function listening(){});
    }
});
```