# BlueMix websocket - VCAP_APP_PORT error EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, websocket, ibm-cloud

I have created a NodeJS websocket server and client

SERVER:

```
//handler server 
app.get('/server', function (req, res) {

  //test websocket
  console.log("server: starting websocket server...");

  var port = (process.env.PORT || 8888); 

  var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

  wss = new WebSocketServer({port: port});
  wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
      ws.on('message', function(message) {
          console.log('server: received: %s', message);
          ws.send('echo: ' + message);
      });
      ws.send('connected');
  });

  console.log("server: listening  websocket on " + appEnv.url + " - port " + port );
  res.send('SERVER - listening websocket on: ' + appEnv.url + " port " + port);

});
```

CLIENT

```
//handler client 
app.get('/client', function (req, res) {

    //var url = 'ws://localhost:8888';//local
    var url = 'ws://<appname>.mybluemix.net';//BlueMix

     var WebSocket = require('ws')     
          , ws = new WebSocket(url);

     console.log('client: calling url: %s', url);

     ws.on('open', function() {
         ws.send('hello');
     });
     ws.on('message', function(message) {
         console.log('client: received: %s', message);
     });

    res.send('CLIENT - WebSocket call done - check the log !!!');

});
```

My expectation was using the port provided from the env VCAP_APP_PORT/PORT on BlueMix. But I get server Error: listen EADDRINUSE. That is reasonable cause that is the port used from the NodeJS runtime server.

Localy all the others ports works (80/443/8888/5555/XXXX etc.) but the client call must be done on that port:

TESTS ON LOCAL:

- SERVER localhost:6007 - port 80 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://localhost > OK
- SERVER localhost:6007 - port 433 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://localhost:443 > OK
- SERVER localhost:6007 - port 8888 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://localhost:8888 > OK
- SERVER localhost:6007 - port 5555 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://localhost:5555 > OK

On BlueMix using the VCAP_APP_PORT is not possible, cause that port is used from NodeJS server (error EADDRINUSE). Using port 80/443 seems not allowed (error EACCES permission denied). Using all other ports works on server side. But the BlueMix firewall blocking all the ports except 80/443 on incoming calls (thats the cause of using Websocket rather than Socket).

TEST ON BLUEMIX:

- SERVER VCAP_APP_PORT (62577-62045) > server Error: listen EADDRINUSE
- SERVER port 80/443 > server Error: listen EACCES (Permission denied)
- SERVER port 8888 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://myapp.mybluemix.net:8888 > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
- SERVER port 8888 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://myapp.mybluemix.net > Error: unexpected server response (500)
- SERVER port 5555 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://myapp.mybluemix.net > Error: unexpected server response (500)
- SERVER port 5555 > OK -- CLIENT call ws://myapp.mybluemix.net:5555 > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

*1. Wich port must be used on BlueMix ?

2. The client call must work on 80/443, Websocket are created for working on incoming call on 80(http) and 443(https) ports... ?*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting the WebSocket server with an existing Express application requires you to share the connection instance rather than opening directly.

From their [documentation](https://github.com/websockets/ws), create the WebSocketServer object with the *server* parameter rather than *port*. See the example below.

Both HTTP and WS traffic received by the platform router will be forwarded to the internal port your application has bound to using the PORT variable.

```
var server = require('http').createServer()
  , url = require('url')
  , WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server })
  , express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , port = 4080;

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.send({ msg: "hello" });
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  var location = url.parse(ws.upgradeReq.url, true);
  // you might use location.query.access_token to authenticate or share sessions
  // or ws.upgradeReq.headers.cookie (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16395220/151312)

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});

server.on('request', app);
server.listen(port, function () { console.log('Listening on ' + server.address().port) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @James Thomas tried a ping pong WS as suggested from you on BlueMix. It works !!

```
var server = require('http').createServer()
  , url = require('url')
  , WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server })
  , express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , port = (process.env.PORT || 4080);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  var location = url.parse(ws.upgradeReq.url, true);
  // you might use location.query.access_token to authenticate or share sessions
  // or ws.upgradeReq.headers.cookie (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16395220/151312)

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('server: on message - received: %s', message);
  });

  console.log('server: waiting connection');
  ws.send('msg from server');
});

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.use(function (req, res) {

    //var url = 'ws://localhost:4080';
    var url = 'ws://<app>.mybluemix.net';

     var WebSocket = require('ws')     
          , ws = new WebSocket(url);

     console.log('client: calling url: %s', url);

     ws.on('open', function() {
         ws.send('msg from client');
         console.log('client: on open - sent msg from client');
     });
     ws.on('message', function(message) {
         console.log('client: on messagge - received: %s', message);
     });

  res.send({ msg: "client call done" });
});

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

server.on('request', app);
server.listen(port, function () { console.log('Listening on ' + server.address().port) })
```