# Arduino WebSocket Client connection issue with node.js ws websocket server

Tags: node.js, websocket, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to make a small WiFi control board with the use of an ESP8266 ESP-201 board.

I used the example provided for WebSocket for Arduino, with a little bit of modification to be able to handle JSON messages. This is the code I got to:

```
/*
 * WebSocketClient.ino
 *
 *  Created on: 24.05.2015
 *
 */

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Hash.h>

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
WebSocketsClient webSocket;

#define USE_SERIAL Serial
ArduinoJson::StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t lenght) {
  switch(type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED: {
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] Connected to url: %s\n",  payload);
      // send message to server when Connected
    }
    break;
    case WStype_TEXT: {
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get text: %s\n", payload);
      String text = String((char *) &payload[0]);
      USE_SERIAL.println(text);
      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(text);
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", root["r"]);
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", root["g"]);
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", root["b"]);
    }
    // send message to server
    break;
    case WStype_BIN:
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get binary lenght: %u\n", lenght);
      hexdump(payload, lenght);
      // send data to server
      break;
    }
}

void setup() {
  USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);
  USE_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);
  USE_SERIAL.println();
  USE_SERIAL.println();
  USE_SERIAL.println();
  for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
    USE_SERIAL.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }
  WiFiMulti.addAP("GamersHeavenLow", "nCore4Life");
  while(WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
  }
  webSocket.begin("192.168.0.104", 3000);
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
}
```

And this is the server side I used to:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: http });
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.use(express.static('public'));
wss.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  var location = url.parse(ws.upgradeReq.url, true);
  // you might use location.query.access_token to authenticate or share sessions
  // or ws.upgradeReq.headers.cookie (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16395220/151312)
  console.log('connected');
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log(message);
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      client.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
  });
  //ws.send('something');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Before I started to work with the JSON encoding it was working for a while, but now it's not. I get the following error:

```
[SETUP] BOOT WAIT 4...
scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
state: 2 -> 3 (0)
state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 2
cnt 

connected with GamersHeavenLow, channel 6
dhcp client start...
ip:192.168.0.101,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.0.1
[SETUP] BOOT WAIT 3...
[SETUP] BOOT WAIT 2...
[SETUP] BOOT WAIT 1...
[WS-Client] connect ws...
[WS-Client] connection to 192.168.0.104:3000 Faild
[WS-Client] client disconnected.
[WSc] Disconnected!
[WS-Client] connect ws...
[WS-Client] connection to 192.168.0.104:3000 Faild
[WS-Client] client disconnected.
[WSc] Disconnected!
```

I believed it must have been the JSON decoding, so I reverted back to the default example, but I still get the same message, connection failed.

So I tried to use the echo websocket server, with which the Arduino code started working.

So I figured out it must be a server side issue, so I tested my node.js websocket server with a pure WebSocket client, but that is also working without a problem.

So basically I have two separate sets of code, which are running in isolation from one another without a problem, but they don't want to play along together.

Any idea what might be causing this?

WebSocket server used: https://github.com/websockets/ws

WebSocket client used on ardruino: https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets

Comment: Remove the var io = require('socket.io')(http); line. It is confusing.

Comment: Removed it, it was a typo :) Beforehand I tried to use that.

Comment: On the error case, what debug lines are shown on the server side ?

Comment: It might be a version mismatch but both libraries are very up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [WS module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) instead of the socket.io.

Comment: Please provide a small example to give some context.

Comment: It is already using : var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

Comment: I'm already using WS, the io was just left there by mistake, because I tried to used that too.