# How to start my websocket connection with my haproxy load balancer?

Tags: websocket, haproxy

I have configured a Haproxy Load Balancer in my VMware Ubuntu OS, and I have a simple websocket server (nodeJS ws) in my windows 10 machine. The question I wan to ask is how can i setup the connection between my Haproxy and my websocket server??

Below is my Haproxy configuration

```
global
  daemon
  maxconn 4096

defaults
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /haproxy?status
  balance roundrobin
  option redispatch
  option forwardfor

  timeout connect 5s
  timeout queue 5s
  timeout client 50s
  timeout server 50s

frontend http-in
  bind *:8000
  default_backend servers

  # Any URL beginning with socket.io will be flagged as 'is_websocket'
  acl is_websocket path_beg /socket.io
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket hdr_beg(Host) -i ws

  # The connection to use if 'is_websocket' is flagged
  use_backend websockets if is_websocket

backend servers
  server server1 192.168.0.201:80
  server server2 192.168.0.201:80

backend websockets
  balance leastconn
  option http-server-close
  option forceclose
  server ws-server1 192.168.0.252:4080 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
  server ws-server2 192.168.0.14:8080 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

Here is my Websocket server script

```
var server = require('http').createServer()
  , url = require('url')
  , WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server })
  , express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , port = 4080;

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.send({ msg: "hello" });
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  var location = url.parse(ws.upgradeReq.url, true);
  // you might use location.query.access_token to authenticate or share sessions 
  // or ws.upgradeReq.headers.cookie (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16395220/151312) 

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something from sevrer');
});

server.on('request', app);
server.listen({port: port, host: '192.168.0.252' }, function () { console.log('Listening on ' + server.address().port) });
```

Comment: On cursory review, your configuration seems valid, so I don't understand what you mean by *"how can i setup the connection"*.  The connections are established when browsers ask for one.