# express-session, connect-redis and einaros/ws

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, node-redis, express-session

I seem to be having some trouble getting Express, express-session, connect-redis and websockets/ws to play together nicely. This most likely has to do with my as yet limited understanding of these modules and coding in general. Most of the code here is taken from the respective examples in the repositories as well as other sources trying to accomplish something similar.

So what we have here is a websocket-enabled app trying to immediately initiate a websocket connection to the server-side app, which does nothing but provide websocket functions currently. This request first hits our NGINX API proxy, which proxies the request to a locally running instance of the Node app.

The Node app should be configured to accept and immediately upgrade the request to websocket, create a unique session id and cookie, which should then be stored inside our Redis box. All of this EXCEPT storage in Redis functions correctly.

The following code WITHOUT connect-redis works (I use the node_redis client directly to query the Redis box for any keys):

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const ws = require('ws');
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient(6379, '10.0.130.10', {no_ready_check: true});
//const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);


var session = require('express-session')({
    //store: new RedisStore({host: '10.0.130.10', port: '6379', ttl: 60, logErrors: true}),
    cookie: {secure: true, maxAge: 3600, httpOnly: true},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: '12345'
});


// Define Express and WS servers
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new ws.Server({ server });


// Client heartbeat
function heartbeat() {
    this.isAlive = true;
}


// WS Websocket
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

    // Obtain Client IP address from NGINX x-forwarded-for proxy header
    let clientIp = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
```

Server output following a request:

---

Listening on: 10031

Session ID: eavjOlls59jtjQd-gZ0EIhqf3_P6sYMr

Session Cookie: {"originalMaxAge":3600,"expires":"2017-05-
27T13:59:19.663Z","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}

Redis reponse for index keys:

---

Enabling connect-redis by uncommenting the relevant sections leads to the following error message on the server when started:

---

/home/ubuntu/app/njs/nl-websocket-dev/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:39
  var Store = session.Store;
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/app/njs/nl-websocket-dev/node_modules/connect-redis/lib/connect-redis.js:39:22)
    at Object. (/home/ubuntu/app/njs/nl-websocket-dev/stackoverflow.js:8:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

---

Note that I initiated express-session in the way I did so I could tie it into websockets/ws. I've tried quite a few configurations, and this is literally the only configuration that allowed express-session and websockets/ws to work together. I got the gist from 'Azmisov' here (which notably excludes connect-redis):

[ExpressJS & Websocket & session sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182651/expressjs-websocket-session-sharing)

Calling express-session into websockets/ws in this manner does function. However, adding connect-redis onto express-session and then calling that combination inside websockets/ws is where the problems start, using this configuration.

Any thoughts on how to get this working are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `session` here:

```
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

Which gets defined later on here:

```
var session = require('express-session')(...);
```

So that's the first issue (`session` being undefined).

The other issue is that `connect-redis` should be passed the result of `require('express-session')`, while your code is trying to pass it an instantiated version of it.

Both issues can be solved like this:

```
const Session    = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(Session);

var session = Session({
  store: new RedisStore(...),
  ...
});
```

I also don't see how `session` is being attached to `app` anywhere in the code you post, but it's not complete so I assume that somewhere you're calling `app.use(session)`.

Comment: First off thanks for your help on this, much appreciated. I see now that the code I pasted is incomplete. Trying to remedy this is a pain on this site I am now discovering. My next comment contains the code that seems important to understanding what I am doing here. I am not calling app.use(session) to get the session data inside websockets.

Comment: `// WS Websocket
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

    session(req, {}, function(){
        let sessionId = req.sessionID;
        console.log('Session ID: ' + sessionId);

        let sessionCookie = req.session.cookie;
        console.log('Session Cookie: ' + JSON.stringify(sessionCookie));
    });
});`

Comment: Okay yes, (`session` being undefined), that makes sense, it is not yet defined when it is called. Your second remark on me trying to pass `connect-redis` an instantiated version of `require('express-session')` is something to chew on. Not clear enough with four hours till dawn. Tried your solution but something is still missing, perhaps due to how I call `express-session` into websockets.

Comment: @rhamstra that last remark (how to use `express-session` with websockets) might actually warrant an entirely new question.

Comment: @robertkep yes I can see how that might be warranted. Now that my immediate issue was resolved by your corrections I think I will do just that so some clear record is left for everyone that might stumble onto something similar. Been digging a bit further. Our client goes for an immediate Opening Handshake/Upgrade request. This seems to bypass any instance of app.use since I get zero ouput on anything configured using that and basic Express structures like app.get. Why this seemingly happens is not yet clear to me, yet ;-) Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @rhamstra upgrade requests always bypass Express because it's not something that Express can handle at all. It's passed to the Websocket server implementation (which listens for [`upgrade`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade) events from the HTTP server).

Comment: @robertkep that last clarification helps, thanks. So then onwards to finding a way to properly implement this. Gonna see about raising another question, in which I will reference this current one. Cheers.

Comment: Proceeding with the follow up on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248437/calling-express-session-backed-by-connect-redis-inside-websockets-ws