# Calling express-session backed by connect-redis inside websockets/ws

Tags: express, websocket, redis, express-session

Okay so here goes. I am trying to to use `express-session` backed by `connect-redis` together with `websockets/ws`. The vast majority of example code I have seen usually includes the use of Express to serve the client a websocket script of some type and then configuring the server app to use the `express-session` middleware to work with session data...with websockets further down the process chain.

My client side app on the other hand immediately initiates an Opening Handshake/Upgrade request, which bypasses Express and heads straight into `websockets/ws`. For this reason I am not able to work with session data through the commonly used `app.use(session(...)` middleware setup.

The below code uses a setup that allows me to call `express-session` inside `websocket/ws` and to put the connection request through `express-session` so I can get at the session data. This works as is shown by the output also below. What does not work however is backing `express-session` by `connect-redis` inside this setup. To check I call a redis client directly to query my redis box after `express-session` has run, no keys are returned.

I have three questions:
1. Is what I am doing below the 'correct' way of integrating `express-session` with `websockets/ws` for the client setup described? 
2. If not what should I be doing?
3. If this is a good way, is it possible to get `connect-redis` working as session store?

Your insights are very welcome.

Server-side code:

```
const express = require('express');
const Session = require('express-session');
const http = require('http');
const ws = require('ws');
const util = require('util');
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient(6379, '10.0.130.10', {no_ready_check: true});
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(Session);
const SessionStore = new RedisStore({host: '10.0.130.10', port: '6379', ttl: 60, logErrors: true});
//const SessionStore = new Session.MemoryStore();


var session = Session({
    store: SessionStore,
    cookie: {secure: true, maxAge: 3600, httpOnly: true},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: '12345'
});


// Define Express and WS servers
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new ws.Server({ server });


// WS Websocket
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

    session(req, {}, function(){
        let sessionId = req.sessionID;
        console.log('SessionID: ' + sessionId);

        let sessionCookie = req.session.cookie;
        console.log('SessionCookie: ' + JSON.stringify(sessionCookie));
    });

    client.keys('*', function(err, reply) {
        // reply is null when the key is missing
        console.log('Redis reponse: ' + reply);
    });
});


server.listen(10031, function listening() {
  console.log('Listening on: ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Server-side console.log output (note the Redis response):

`Listening on: 10031
SessionID: Oi8AdsoZTAm3hRLmxPfGo43Kmmj_Yd6F
SessionCookie: {"originalMaxAge":3599,"expires":"2017-05-29T17:45:54.467Z","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"}
Redis reponse:`

Reference:
[express-session, connect-redis and einaros/ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218539/express-session-connect-redis-and-einaros-ws)
Reference:
[ExpressJS & Websocket & session sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182651/expressjs-websocket-session-sharing)

Comment: Session sharing suggests that you want Express and the Websocket handlers to share a session object. However, your Express app doesn't seem to be doing anything, so what exactly is the point of having a shared session in that situation?

Comment: @robertklep at the moment I want to be able to track users (adding other user specific identifiers as well, while connected to the system, and store the tracking data centrally so it can be accessed from other devices/services in our environment as well. I am guessing at some point we will start interacting with Express and include authentication.

Comment: Inside the callback you pass to `session`, try explicitly calling [`req.session.save()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessionsavecallback), and from _its_ callback, call `client.keys('*', ...)`.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly! I am now able to use `SessionStore.get(sessionId, function (error, session){...});` to retrieve the data pertaining to the current session from the Store. Thank you once again for your assistance sir, much appreciated!

Comment: I do wonder if the session is sticky, because from I can see, there's no way that the session middleware can actually _set_ a session cookie. If you reload, my guess is that you'll get a new session id each time (also, to prevent false positives, make sure that there aren't any existing session cookies stored in your browser before testing).

Comment: Indeed currently the session is not 'sticky', a browser reload causes the old websocket to be expired after timing out, and the new websocket receives a new sessionID. However, I have seen some examples of setting a cookie on the initial `websockets` upgrade request. Doing that would not work in this setup however since at that point `express-session` is not yet in play to actually provide the sessionID for the cookie?

Comment: That's correct. I was initially looking at the [`headers`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#event-headers) event that the WS server emits, and where you can set additional headers (like a session cookie), but it looks synchronous, so you can't run `session(req, {}, ...)` to have `express-session` generate a new session for which you can add a cookie header. All in all, it seems like you're not going to be able to use `express-session` very easily.

Comment: Challenges abound. Fortunately for me at this point, though limited in function it is still useable. If you don't mind my asking, how did you reach the conclusion that the `headers` event is synchronous?

Comment: Because it doesn't provide a callback to call after the headers have been set.