# Is there a way to get session data in express.js outside of routers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, websocket, express-session

I tried using cookies to lookup session data (express-session module) in mongodb using the connect-mongo package (npm). This all stemmed from the fact that i would need to use several parts of the session data to enable functionalities in my app like getting an authors name and email from a session data set from login, accessed from a WebSocket (ws module). Do i even need to store the session in a database? my dead end was when i realized i needed to use cookie parser as a part of the connect-mongo lookup which requires "req" (getting the cookie from the client was confusing enough for me as of now), and i don't think i can use that, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the express-session module.  That is very easy to use and does most all the work for you as you don't have to deal with cookies directly at all

Comment: @jfriend00 Right, so i'm guessing i'm going to need a session store (for multiple clients/authors)? I'm still not quite sure how to reference a session without "req", express-session states that, "This module now directly reads and writes cookies on req/res". Would i need some sort of middleware? and if so how do i write the middleware?

Comment: express-session is middleware already and it comes with a built-in memory store or can be used with all sorts of database connectors.  You'd have to explain in more detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish for any more detailed help.  Right now your question is very generic.  Please show exactly what the problem is that you're  trying to solve.

Comment: For session sharing between Express and ws, you can see [Express/ws session sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182651/expressjs-websocket-session-sharing).

Comment: The post you mentioned was close enough, i understand how the database connectors work a little bit better now, just trying to pass the client/author credentials from the express-session outside a route or without "req". Now i see that i can actually somehow pass the session data inside the WebSocket connection? still couldn't get it to work, someone on GitHub said upgradeReq was deprecated so i'm gonna experiment to find out a better method.